# connecting to SQL database on my web server from Raspberry pi

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi

I am trying to access an SQL database that reside on my web server from a Raspberry Pi - using python.

I tried using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect(host="abc.co.uk.mysql"
               user="USER NAME"
               passwd="PASSWORD"
               db="NAME OF DATABASE")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME")
for row in cur.fetchall():
print row[0]
```

I receive the following error when executing!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getDatafromSQL", line 7, in <module>
    db='alisoliman_co_u') 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'alisoliman.co.uk.mysql'        (111)")
```

Any idea why could that be? Is there any ways that I can connect to a MySQL database on a server?

Comment: `alisoliman.co.uk.mysql` is not a valid internet address. Doesn't the server have a valid IP? An internet domain does most certainly *not* end in `.mysql`.

Comment: `alisoliman.co.uk.mysql` is my host name I also tried the IP(10.246.16.201) but didnt make any different

Comment: And can you connect to the database with any other tool?

Comment: I managed to access it on my android APP by using php script! Is there a tool that I can use to confirm if the db is accessible directly?

Comment: 10.0.0.0/8 is a [reserved subnet](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918). Ergo it is not accessible from the broader Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you made the right indentation for the print statement under the for loop (the last line of your code).

I don't know which distro are you running on your Raspberry PI, but I've tried your code on my RPI (Arch distro), doing a query on a simple table on the mysql server running in the RPI, and it works well. I've did some changes but I don't believe that these changes are relevant for the right flow of the query.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn_1=mdb.Connection(db='NAME OF DATABASE', host='localhost', user='USER NAME', passwd='PASSWORD')
cur = conn_1.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM rkn_env")
for row in cur.fetchall():
 print row[0]
```

FYI, you can capture the traffic between RPI and the host where the MySQL server is running using tcpdump. This tool has saved me many times...

Lastly, did you check if your MySQL daemon is running and listening (e.g. using netstat -anp) ?